# Can't locate on device's local storage nativescript file-system generated directory

Tags: javascript, typescript, nativescript

I'm creating an audio file and it seems working fine because the indicator that it records and audio shows no error. But after the app generates the directory, I can't locate it on local storage.

I am using this code

`var audioFolder = fs.knownFolders.currentApp().getFolder("audio");`

This code shows 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1wTk.png)

This what I get when I tried to locate it on local storage 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WONOn.jpg)

Comment: is this on emulator and actially device as well? I am assuming it's android only. Have you checked on ios as well?

Comment: I have tried this one on Android only using actual device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current app directory is something that is only visible to your app, so you will not be able to locate it with any file manager apps.

If you like other apps to access those audio files, be visible in any file manager apps, then use external storage directory.